# Best way to reduce TLS handshake latency according to geo-locations?

Tags: ssl, server, openssl, apache2, tls1.2

For example, the TLS handshake latency increases from ~100ms (Europe) to 1sec+ (Asia).

What is the best way to reduce this latency? Is it mandatory to replicate your website in different servers while they use the same database?

(Apache2.2, mod_ssl, TLS 1.2, lets-encrypt)

Comment: You can reduce the TLS handshake latency by buying mirrors all over the globe, or just use Cloudflare and you get latency reduction and more (traffic optimization, DDoS protection) for free.

Comment: @Martheen You mean their reverse proxy service ? It's an interesting alternative. Whatever in all quoted cases you have to set up multiple servers. The site doesn't have huge data assets, they are very low (so pretty fast to serve). But the SSL handshake is the main reason that slow their transfert. I wonder if there's anyway to improve that SSL handshake without website replication.

Comment: You do understand how Cloudflare works right? They (and other CDN providers) would be the one your visitor hit. If they're in HK, they get the near zero latency since it's the CDN server that commit the handshake and all. All the static content also immediately delivered. Meanwhile, it's going back and forth between your actual site and the browser for dynamic content. No need to replicate anything. Just register/purchase the service, setup the DNS, you're done. Make a sample site and test it yourself  so you'll find your answer in an hour or so rather than pondering if you need to buy servers

Comment: @Martheen Thank you for this discovery.